# How to set JWT token to Stomp header while using Ocelot api gateway

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, stomp, ocelot

I am using Stomp to establish a connection between frontend and backend. I use alb ingress to do the proxy and use Ocelot as API gateway to do the authentication. It works fine with normal http request. I did some search, seems like it is not possible to set a header for Stomp. A workaround that I came up with is to pass the token as part of the URL. However I do not know how to get it in Ocelot or in ingress. I used `@stomp/stompjs` this package for stomp. My frontend uses React and backend is Java spring

The configuration for the stomp client

```
client.configure({
      brokerURL: 'wss://localhost:8080/stomp',
      connectHeaders:{
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
      }
    });
```

The Ocelot part

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/stomp",
      "DownstreamScheme": "ws",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "backend",
          "Port": 8080
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/stomp",
      "UpstreamHost": "localhost",

      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "ProjectAPI",
        "AllowedScopes": [
          "project-api"
        ]
      },
      "AddHeadersToRequest": {
        "tenantId": "Claims[tenantId] > value > |"
      }
    }
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why is it not possible to set a header in STOMP? The STOMP protocol clearly [supports headers](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Frames_and_Headers).

Comment: @JustinBertram I follow this documentation https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/Client.html#connectHeaders I don't see an option to add header except connectHeaders. The connectHeaders is different than the http header (I dont know the differences tho). The Ocelot seems not able to fetch the token in the connectheader tho

Comment: Does Ocelot understand STOMP? STOMP doesn't use HTTP. It just uses TCP and defines its own "frames modelled on HTTP" (as noted in the specification). The [`CONNECT` frame supports a handful of headers](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#CONNECT_or_STOMP_Frame), but an authorization token isn't one of them.

Comment: @JustinBertram I don't know, I couldn't find any document online discussing this. How do people do the authentication in the api gateway for STOMP? Most of the answer I found is do it in the backend

Comment: I know STOMP, but I don't know API gateways so I can't say how people normally do STOMP authentication in the gateway. If you can't find any documentation on how to do it in your gateway then I guess your only option is to do it in the backend.

Comment: @JustinBertram If I do the authentication in the backend in the ChannelInterceptor. Will the authentication happen only once for the connection? If so that is good. I don't want to authenticate each message

Comment: Authentication should happen *once* at the connection-level, not at the message-level.

Comment: @JustinBertram yeah, my question is does the ChannelInterceptor do the authentication in the connection-level?

Comment: I'm not a Spring expert so I can't say exactly what `ChannelInterceptor` does or doesn't do. However, I can say that the only STOMP frame that has anything to authenticate is the `CONNECT` frame. No other frame carries any credentials.

Comment: @JustinBertram thank you!